# Using User Form to update specific cells

Tags: vba

I created a user form with two combo boxes ("cmb1" and "cmb2"), each referring to a range of values. I need to:

1) Permanently show this user form on a specific worksheet (let's call with "ws")

2) Update values of ws.Cells(B,4) to match the value chosen by user on cmb1 and similarly, ws.Cells(A,2) to the value chosen by user on cmb2.

I have created a CommandButton ("Enter")on the user form as well. The updates need to happen once that button is clicked.

My code is giving me a run-time error on me.cmb1

```
Private Sub Enter_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ws")

ws.Cells(B, 4) = Me.cmb1
ws.Cells(A, 2) = Me.cmb2
End Sub
```

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: I think you need `Me.cmb1.Value`, also for the following line you need to add `.value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using .Cells which requires a number for both the row and column reference. The run-time error is being triggered because you are using a letter for your column reference.

You have two options to save the values from the comboboxes (probably more, but two simple ways).

Option 1 - .Cells (note that it is row first, then column)

```
ws.Cells(4,2) = Me.cmb1.Value
ws.Cells(2,1) = Me.cmb.value
```

Option 2 - .Range

```
ws.Range("B4") = Me.cmb1.Value
ws.Cells("A2") = Me.cmb.value
```

See http://excelmatters.com/referring-to-ranges-in-vba/ for more info